# While loop to input from multiple texbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have 20 textBoxes on a vba userform these textBoxes are supposed to take their values from a barcode reader and i created a while loop to take the values from those textboxes and input them on the next empty row , but when i check the results i get 2 problems

```
J = 0
While J < 20
LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 
ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = Now()
ws.Range("B" & LastRow).Value = Me.Controls("TextBox" & J + 1).Value 
ws.Range("D" & LastRow).Value = Me.Controls("TextBox" & J + 2).Value 
ws.Range("I" & LastRow).Value = TextBox21.Value
J = J + 1
Wend
```

1. The Quantity inserted on column D is Repeated on the Next Row Column B
2. Even If the TextBoxes are Empty It is still placing data As you can see on the highlighted in Red

Comment: you are using J+1 and J+2, so when J iterates, your new J+1 =  old J+2

Comment: what do you actually want to happen?  looks like you're saying B = textbox 1, D = textbox 2, then you iterate and B = textbox 2, D = textbox 3.  I assume you want some modifier to increase J higher, e.g., B = 2*J+1 and D = 2*J+2 or something

Comment: Yes I actually did that because I have to take input from 2 textboxes on one row and the TextBoxes are not ordered sequentially but with odd and even , so its like Textbox1 and  Textbox2 for one row and then TextBox3 and TextBox4 for another.

Answer (score 1):

Will post as an answer so it can be marked as such, though I listed this in a comment:

```
J = 0
While J < 20
    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 
    ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = Now()
    ws.Range("B" & LastRow).Value = Me.Controls("TextBox" & J*2 + 1).Value 
    ws.Range("D" & LastRow).Value = Me.Controls("TextBox" & J*2 + 2).Value 
    ws.Range("I" & LastRow).Value = TextBox21.Value
    J = J + 1
Wend
```

May want to check your J max after this...

row 1 uses J = 0, so textbox 1, textbox 2

row 2 uses j = 1, so textbox 1*2+1 (3) and textbox 1*2+2 (4)

row 3 uses j =2, so textbox 2*2+1 (5) and textbox 2*2+2 (6)

etc.